# Blazor QuickGrid: how to create a column without populating RenderFragment?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am still exploring what Blazor's [QuickGrid](https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/main/src/QuickGrid/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid) can do.

And I faced one annoying problem here. I want to add one more column that will be used to render checkboxes in the header and in the body. I want this column to be rendered by providing only type parameter, like this:

```
<QuickGrid Data="@data">
    <CheckboxColumn Title="Checkbox" /> // my custom column
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.Id)" Format="C" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.Name)" />
    <TemplateColumn Title="Actions">
        <button>@context.Price</button>
    </TemplateColumn>
</QuickGrid>
```

---

From the docs we know that we `may define columns by adding components derived from the ColumnBase<TGridItem> base class.` So, I created my custom class like this:

```
public class CheckboxColumn<TGridItem> : ColumnBase<TGridItem>
{
    // abstract method implementation
}
```

The problem is that in the end, the grid doesn't renders my column (means that in the browser I can see all of the columns except the first one). Why?

**Remarks:**

1. I tried to debug and examine what's happening there. On the first render of the grid, I can see that all 4 columns were collected by this call `Grid.AddColumn(this)` in the `ColumnBase.razor`. But then, due to invoke of a callback, the grid re-renders, clears the collection of the columns, and renders `@ChildContent` again, means that `Grid.AddColumn(this)` gets called again. But this time, the first `this` is the 2nd column.

So, in short: on initial render we get all 4 columns -> at specific time re-rendering happens -> collection of columns gets cleared -> we get only 3 columns (all except the first one)

I hope you could follow the logic.

2. Since `CheckboxColumn` is derived from `ColumnBase`, we can use, for example, a `HeaderTemplate` which is a `RenderFragment<>`. If we provide something in the `HeaderTemplate` for `CheckboxColumn` -- everything renders fine. But I don't want to provide any `RenderFragment`s in there.

**UPD-1**
If `Align` parameter is provided to `CheckboxColumn` -- everything is fine! But it still doesn't answer the question for me...

**UPD-2** If I am not mistaken, this statement (`All of the parameters are from a set of known types† or any primitive type that hasn't changed since the previous set of parameters were set.`) answers, why my `CheckboxColumn` does not get re-rendered. So how can I force re-render?

Comment: Can you add the usage of CheckboxColumn to be complete?

Comment: @HH in the first code snippet you can see that I am using it as the first column of the grid. It should act like TemplateColumn but without a RenderFragment. At this point I want to see the title at least.

Comment: O yes, I fixated on that last one.

Comment: I don't quite understand how custom columns work in QuickGrid, but if you just want to add checkboxes, you can use `<TemplateColumn Title="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></TemplateColumn>`. You can bind data through `@bind` in input.

Comment: @Chen I need a built-in `CheckboxColumn` column

Answer (score 0):

I would like myself an empty column which I use for CSS index number but I believe it is not possible at the moment, due to current QuickGrid implementation so we have to do the ceremony for now .

I have created some bare minimum for you which works for me, two examples:

```
<EmptyColumn Title="#" TGridItem="CorporateUserDto" Property="new()" />
<EmptyColumn2 Title="#" Property="new()" />
```

The first one is passing the type `TGridItem`, and so it is generic.

The second one has a hard coded type, which you will see below but **must** be the same type as your TGridItem otherwise it won't work.

```
public class EmptyColumn<TGridItem> : ColumnBase<TGridItem>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dummy Property otherwise it doesn't render
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter] public TGridItem? Property { get; set; }

    protected override void CellContent(RenderTreeBuilder builder, TGridItem item) 
    => builder.AddContent(0, “Hi”);
}

public class EmptyColumn2 : ColumnBase<CorporateUserDto>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dummy Property otherwise it doesn't render
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter] public CorporateUserDto? Property { get; set; }

    protected override void CellContent(RenderTreeBuilder builder, CorporateUserDto item)
    => builder.AddContent(0, “Hello”);
}
```

Another example is this one, which is again flexible as I can select any boolean property I want so it is type checked.

```
<CheckboxColumn TGridItem="CorporateUserDto" Property="@(c => c.IsLondon)" />
```

I used this implementation for `CheckboxColumn` , but because it is just boolean, it is simlified
https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/blob/main/src/QuickGrid/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid/Columns/PropertyColumn.cs

An alternative or combination with the custom columns is the flexibility to add them dynamically in the easiest way, e.g. using some manager e.g. we can add a column as simply as calling this `AddSpaceshipId()`.

```
@code {
    private bool _isLoading = true;        
    private List<SpaceshipDto> _items = new();
    private ColumnManager<SpaceshipDto> _columnManager = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _columnManager.AddSpaceshipId();
        _columnManager.AddSpaceshipName();
        _columnManager.Add(new() { Property = p => p.LastDepartureDate, Title = "Last Departure" });
        _columnManager.Add(new() { Property = p => p.LastDepartureDays, Title = "Days", Align = Align.Center });

        _items = await Service.GetSpaceships();

        _isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

And then we can render it here

```
<QuickGrid Items=“@_items.AsQueryable()” Class=“table table-sm table-index table-striped small table-blazor table-fit mb-0 table-thead-sticky” Theme=“earth”>
   <EmptyColumn Title=“#” TGridItem=“SpaceshipDto” Property=“new()” />
    @foreach (var col in _columnManager.Get())
    {
        <PropertyColumn Title=“@col.Title”
           Property=“@col.Property”
           Sortable=“@col.Sortable”
           Align=“@col.Align” />
    }
</QuickGrid>
```

I am preparing a blog post regarding the `ColumnManager`. I will leave a link in the comment once it is done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am actually done with this issue already. Making my own grid and components that will publish in the near future.