# Due to Blazor Change Detection API, component re-rendering get skipped. How to avoid?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am working on Blazor project (.NET 5). I got a problem with components rendering.
I have parent component with `ChildContent` as `RenderFragment` inside. And I use it like this:

```
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent1 Title="Component1"></ChildComponent1>
    <ChildComponent2 Title="Component2" SampleEnum="SampleEnum.Bar"></ChildComponent2>
</ParentComponent>
```

Each `ChildComponent` inherits `ChildComponentBase`:

```
public class ChildComponent1 : ChildComponentBase 
{
   // some code
}
```

`ChildComponentBase` contains `ParentComponent` as cascading parameter and 2 parameters: one of them is `string` ([Immutable for Blazor Change Detection API](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/ChangeDetection.cs)) and another one is `enum` (which is not Immutable) just for sake of example. And here we also

```
public partial class ChildComponentBase
{
     [CascadingParameter]
     public ParentComponent Parent { get; set; } = default !;

     [Parameter]
     public string? Title { get; set; } // Immutable

     [Parameter]
     public SampleEnum SampleEnum { get; set; } // not Immutable
}
```

In `ParentComponent` I use a strategy of deferred rendering. `Defer` component looks like this and being used in `ParentComponent`:

```
// This is used to move its body rendering to the end of the render queue so we can collect
// the list of child components first.
public class Defer : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree( RenderTreeBuilder builder )
    {
        builder.AddContent( 0, ChildContent );
    }
}
```

In my project on first render I collect all `ChildComponent` from `ChildContent` like this:

*ChildComponentBase.razor*

```
@{
    Parent.AddChild(this); // Parent is cascading parameter
}
```

And then I invoke a callback to process data. `ParentComponent` looks like this:
*ParentComponent.razor*

```
<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed>
    @{
        StartCollectingChildren();
    }
    @ChildContent

    <Defer>
        @{
            FinishCollectingChildren();

            ProcessDataAsync();
        }

        @foreach (var o in _childComponents)
        {
            <p>@o.Title</p>
        }
    </Defer>
</CascadingValue>
```

*ParentComponent.razor.cs*

```
public partial class ParentComponent
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private List<ChildComponentBase> _childComponents = new();
    private bool _firstRender = true;
    private bool _collectingChildren; // Children might re-render themselves arbitrarily. We only want to capture them at a defined time.

    protected async Task ProcessDataAsync()
    {
        if (_firstRender)
        {
            //imitating re-render just like it would be an async call
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            _firstRender = false;
        }
    }

    public void AddChild(ChildComponentBase child)
    {
        _childComponents.Add(child);
    }

    private void StartCollectingChildren()
    {
        _childComponents.Clear();
        _collectingChildren = true;
    }

    private void FinishCollectingChildren()
    {
        _collectingChildren = false;
    }
}
```

Due to invoke of callback - re-rendering happens. And due to re-rendering `StartCollectingChildren()` is getting called again. This time on second render of `ParentComponent` the `ChildComponent1` doesn't re-render, because `Blazor Change Detection API` skips it (because it contains only an Immutable parameter `Title` while `ChildComponent2` in addition contains `enum` parameter).

**Question: how to make this `ChildComponent1` get re-rendered anyway?**

I also added a [Sample Project](https://github.com/AleksandrSt/SampleProject) with code described above for you to try it out yourself.

I tried everything I could find in the google. The best workaround I found is to cache children collection on first render, but it looks dirty and could cause issues in a future.

Comment: [Polite] Wow.  My primary question is why?  Why do you need to "defer" rendering?  I'll quite happily look at your code, but my gut sense is there's a simpler solution to your root problem.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75060043/60761

Comment: 'immutable' is not the point here, Blazor just has a small list of types that it compares before deciding to re-render. An enum is immutable, just not on that list.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - the Defer trick is from some sample code by the Blazor team. It might be in Quickgrid, I can't check right now.

Comment: @HH - Yes it's in `QuickGrid`.  I'd still like to understand why the OP want's to use it.  Are they trying to build something similar to `QuickGrid`?  The code block is marked **For internal use only. Do not use.** for a reason.  You need to really understand components and the Render process before you try and shuffle the Render process.

Comment: @Aleksandr - A lot of the code you've shown is lifted from the Microsoft `QuickGrid`.  Are you trying to build something similar to QuickGrid?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis , we are trying to use Quickgrid. Here is just a visually simplified example of the Quickgrid’s main processes. The question still remains.

Comment: There's a mismatch between the code above and the code in the repo.  Above you show `ProcessDataAsync` , in the code you have `OnAfterRender`

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, oh, probably forgot to commit latest changes. But it is actually not a big deal, code acts same way. But yes.. sorry, OnAfterRender should be a ProcessDataAsync and must be called in the .razor

Comment: See my answer.  Forgive my initial WOW, I was surprised by the complexity without any context!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis as desmondische have already said, we are trying to extend QuickGrid to have predefined columns. And yes, we forgot to commit change we made during writing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix to your problem is to modify the cascade and remove `IsFixed`.

Once you do that any component that captures the cascade will always be rendered because `this` is an object and therefore fails the equality check.

You can also drive render events on sub components that don't have object parameters using a Guid Cascade.  Assign a new Guid to the mapped parameter whenever you want to force a render on any sub component the captures the cascade.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In docs I’ve read that Microsoft suggest using `IsFixed` for a better performance. Is it safe to remove it in terms of the Quickgrid?

Comment: So, looks like it’s better to provide some parameter that will trigger re-rendering. And maybe make this parameter `EditorRequired` then. Only if there is nothing else to do of course…?

Comment: Thank you for the solution provided, good point. As @desmondische said we need to make a small research regarding if it safe to remove `IsFixed` in terms of performance.

Comment: `IsFixed` informs the `ParameterView` object for each component to exclude the parameter from it's *May Have Changed* calculation (which is what drives the Renderer's yes/no decision on calling `SetParametersAsync` on a component.  Yes it impacts performance by forcing a render on every render of the parent, but that's what you want.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, I haven’t noticed your edit earlier. Could you please tell more about *Guid Cascade*? I am not quite sure I fully understand how to implement it.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, ok, seems like we got it. Thanks for an advice.